# How does Tkinter keep track of its widgets when used with classes?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *


class SampleClass:

    def __init__(self, master):  
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        self.printButton = Button(master, text = "PrintButton", command=self.printMessage)
        self.printButton.pack(side = LEFT)

    def printMessage(self):
        print("Hulk Smash!")

root = Tk()
samp = SampleClass(root)

root.mainloop()
```

The Tkinter `root` is passed to the class as a reference only once. So, when the root changes (pressing a button, or entering some text using entry widgets), the state of `root` is changed. How does the class `samp` know that the `root` has changed? I understand that the `root.mainloop()` method makes calls to the `root` in a loop but the class `samp` seems to have no idea of the changing reference. What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'the `class` samp seems to have no idea of the changing reference'. Each widget has an attribute `master` which contains the parent window/widget and each widget has a `children` attribute which contains the dictionary of all children of the widget. So all widgets inside the `samp` class keep tracks of their parent and children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tkinter is a thin wrapper around a Tcl interpreter which has loaded the "tk" package. When you create a widget (eg: `Frame(master)`), this creates an object in the Tcl interpreter. It is the Tcl interpreter that keeps hold of the reference to the master widget, and it is the Tcl interpreter that responds to changes.